# Converting dtype: object to integer for a column that has numbers with spaces between them

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe that I am trying to remove the spaces between the numbers in the value column and then use pd.to_numeric to change the dtype.  THe current dtype of value is an object.

```
    periodFrom  value
1   17.11.2020  28 621 240
2   18.11.2020  30 211 234
3   19.11.2020  33 065 243
4   20.11.2020  34 811 330
```

I have tried multiple variations of this but can't work it out:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.strip()
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Comment: You were so close to the target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to apply `.str.split()` first in order to split by whitespaces(even if the anyone of them has more than one character length), then concatenate (`''.join()`) while removing those whitespaces along with converting to integers(`int()`) such as

```
j=0
for i in df['value'].str.split():
    df['value'][j]=int(''.join(i))
    j+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df['value'].replace({' ':''}, regex=True)
```

Or

```
df['value'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(' ', '', str(x)))
```

And add to both `.astype(int)`.

Comment: great that it helped!